# How to perform conditional map in Java 8?

Tags: json, java-8, java-stream

I have the below serialized JSON

```
{
   "id1":[
      {
         "idTypeA":{
            "idTypeB":{
               "idTypeC":{
                  "idTypeD":{ 
                    "name": "name1"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and below classes to help in deserialization

```
public class IdTypeD {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}

public class IdTypeC {
    @JsonProperty("idTypeD")
    private IdTypeD idTypeD;
}

public class IdTypeB {
    @JsonProperty("idTypeC")
    private IdTypeC idTypeC
}

public class IdTypeA {
    @JsonProperty("idTypeB")
    private IdTypeB idTypeB
}
```

and I have the below code to deserialize it and get a map of the form `{"id1" : "name1"}`

```
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<IdTypeA>>> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<IdTypeA>>>() { };
        HashMap<String, List<IdTypeA>> mapping =  mapper.convertValue(idToNameMap, typeRef);

        mapping.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(l -> l.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                        .map(opta -> opta.map(IdTypeA::getIdTypeB))
                        .map(optb -> optb.map(IdTypeB::getIdTypeC))
                        .map(optc -> optc.map(IdTypeC::getIdTypeD))
                        .map(optd -> optd.map(IdTypeD::getName))
                        .map(optv -> optv.orElse(""))
                        .map(m -> result.put(l.getKey(), m.isEmpty() ? null : m))
                        .count())
                .count();
```

Now I have a requirement where IdTypeC can have another property called idTypeE whose class contains the `name` property, similar to IdTypeD as shown below

```
public class IdTypeC {
    @JsonProperty("idTypeD")
    private IdTypeD idTypeD;

    @JsonProperty("idTypeE")
    private IdTypeD idTypeE;
}

public class IdTypeE {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

For example, I can have a serialized JSON like below:

```
{
   "id1":[
      {
         "idTypeA":{
            "idTypeB":{
               "idTypeC":{
                  "idTypeE":{ 
                    "name": "name1"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

can I optimize the above code so that I can deserialize a serialized JSON like this as well into a map of the form `{"id1" : "name1"}` ?
So basically I want to attend to both the cases with a common code -

1. idTypeD nested under idTypeC
2. idTypeE nested under idTypeC

Really appreciate your patience, and would be open to ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Will this be the case that the user will have both `idTypeE` or `idTypeD`?

Comment: Don’t use side effects like `result.put(…)` in a `map` function. A practical example of what can go wrong when using an API against its intent, starting with Java 9, `count()` will not evaluate these mapping functions, as they are not needed to count the elements.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar No, the user will have either idTypeE or idTypeD

Comment: @Holger point noted, thank you